# Using a variable from another condition in PHP

Tags: php, class, variables, post, get

I have this code:

```
if(!isset($_GET["act"]))
{
    $display->display("templates/install_main.html");
    if(isset($_POST["proceed"]))
    {
        $prefix = $_POST["prefix"];
    }
}

if($_GET["act"] == "act")
{
    echo $prefix;
}
```

Basically I've made a similar question before, thing is, HOW can I make the variable accessible? please mention if there is any way to do so, even with changing the way it's done (someone told me it's possible with a class but not quite sure how it can be done), or any other way to make it accessible.

Thanks!

Comment: Since both your `$_GET['act']` conditions can't be `true` at the same time, the `$prefix` variable cannot exist in the second condition. This is not about "variable access" or scope, it's about simple logic.

Comment: No it's not! I tried...

Comment: `$echo` will either never be attempted to be echoed or will never be defined when attempted.  `if(!isset($_GET["act"]))` and `if($_GET["act"] == "act")` cannot both be true.

Answer (score 3):

PHP's variable scope is function-level. $prefix would be available in your second `if()` **IF** the other if()'s evaluated to true and actually executed that `$prefix = ...` code.

e.g.

```
if (true) {
    $foo = 'bar'; // always executes
}
if (false) {
    $baz = 'qux'; // never executes
}
echo $foo; // works just fine
echo $baz; // undefined variable, because $baz='qux' never executed.
```

Also note that PHP is not capable of time travel:

```
echo $x; // undefined variable;
$x = 'y';
echo $y; // spits out 'y'
```

"earlier" code will not have "later" variables available, because the code that actually creates/assigns values to those variables won't have executed yet.

Comment: So how do I actually fix it?

Comment: fix your logic. Your two outer ifs are logical opposites. the first only goes true if $_GET['act'] DOESN'T exist, while the second one (which uses $prefix) requires it to exist AND have a value. they can't both be true. If $_GET['act'] exists, then $prefix won't get set. And if it does exist, then $prefix won't be available for use.

Comment: What I am trying to do with the ifs is to show different HTML parts and different code snippet according to their stage at the page, and I still want it that way, what should I do to keep this as well as for it to be logically coded?